# c++ unhandled exception LoadImage() with MAKEINTRESOURCE

Tags: c++, resources, loadimage

I'm having a problem to add a bitmap image to a static control box, i got an unhandled exception when i run my program. Here's my code.

FROM RC FILE :

```
ID_ICON1    BITMAP  "icon1.bmp"
```

CPP FILE :

```
HANDLE bIcon1;
HWND hIcon;             
hIcon = CreateWindowEx(0, "Static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE|SS_BITMAP, 250, 100, 100, 100, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
bIcon1 = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ICON1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

If i use full path i get no error and the bmp shows correctly :

```
bIcon1 = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "c:\\icon1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

Thanks for helping :)

edit:
the line of the exception is this one:

```
bIcon1 = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ICON1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

the message exception is :
Unhandled exception at 0x7768e41b in windows2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001f4.

> windows2.exe!WndProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int msg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 153 + 0x27 bytes C++

Comment: Clearly the OS is upset about you using the word "icon" for a bitmap and refuses to give you a good line number or exception message.  If you want somebody to debug your code for you then post a minimal repro project to a file sharing service.

Comment: the exception is a this line : bIcon1 = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ICON1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `LR_LOADFROMFILE` but the second parameter is not a file name. Delete that flag.